# Redraw canvas on object property change

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm building small library for object management on html5 canvas. Each object has x and y properties, saying where the object should be positioned on canvas. I would like to copy DOM property modification (when I do elm.style.left = '100px', changes gets instantly reflected) to my library. Rendering is managed in special function, so I would like to call this function every time any object gets modified (+some other functions, like collision detection if set,...).

---

EDIT:
I have an object like this:

```
{
    x: 10,
    y:10,
    ...
}
```

When I do `obj.x = 20;`, I need to redraw the canvas with new object coordinates.

Comment: can you please go more into detail?

Answer (score 0):

**[ Changed answer based on questioners comments ]**

You have object property changes potentially occurring from several sources:

- From your javascript code,
- From the user (mousing, etc),
- From the physics routine

To handle this, set up an master-object that holds the array of objects and some status properties:

```
var universe={
    objects:[],
    requiresRender:false,
};
```

Then  you can organize your render() function like this:

- Do physics on universe.objects
- If physics changed anything then redraw everything

Example render function:

```
function render(universe){

    // if there's no work to do then return

    if(!universe.requiresRender){ return; }

    // do physics resolutions

    doPhysics(universe.objects);

    // if any source changed any objects properties then redraw

    if(universe.requiresRender){    
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<universe.objects.length;i++){
            // redraw  object[i] now
        }
        universe.requiresRender=false;
    }

}
```

The doPhysics() function changes object properties based on your physics:

```
function doPhysics(objects){

    // do your physics now (collision tests, etc)
    // (don't redraw here...just change object properties)

    // if you changed any property on any object 
    // then request re-rendering
    universe.requiresRender=true;

}
```

One aspect of physics is that changing 1 object may cause cascading effects on other objects.

For example, rectangle A may collide with rectangle B, so A bounces off B.  As A bounces it may further collide with rectangle C.

This means you might have to recursively call doPhysics() to resolve all object interactions.

It’s typical that there isn’t enough time/resources to resolve all object interactions so physics engines will often do a fixed number of physics recusions rather than attempt to fully resolve all object interactions.

In all but trivial physics environments your render function must also limit the extent it will resolve physics.

So your render() function might instead look like this:

```
var universe={
    objects:[],
    requiresRender:false,
    physicsIterations=3,
};


function render(universe){

    // if there's no work to do then return

    if(!universe.requiresRender){ return; }

    // do the required number of physics resolutions

    for(var i=0;i<universe.physicsIterations;i++){
        doPhysics(universe.objects);
    }

    // if any source changed any objects properties then redraw

    if(universe.requiresRender){    
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<universe.objects.length;i++){
                // redraw  object[i] now
        }
        universe.requiresRender=false;
    }
}
```

If the user changes any objects properties set the requiresRender flag:

```
universe.requiresRender=true;
```

If your javascript changes any objects properties set the requiresRender flag:

```
universe.requiresRender=true;
```

By using the requiresRender flag, you can rely on a loop to call render() periodically to keep the objects properly drawn.

This way you don’t need to render() with every property change (rendering with every property change reduces performance).

You can use requestAnimationFrame to efficiently synchronize your rendering with the refresh cycle of the hardware display.  So requestAnimationFrame results in efficient rendering.

This requestAnimationFrame loop will execute up to 60 times per second.

```
function loop(time){

    // keep the loop going
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    // use javascript to make any desired object property changes

    // do a render 
    render();

}
```

**Also**

You might check out how a physics engine handles property-updates + physics + redraws.

Box2d is a nice example: http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sorry to say this, but you absolutely misunderstood my question. I already know everything you are telling me.

Comment: So please explain your question to me :)  If you're looking for a browser event that notifies you of changes to a canvas element's position then DOMAttrModified works for some-but not all, browsers (you must do polling to be fully cross browser compatible). Or are you looking for javascript getters/setters?  These are not recommended to automate object changes into canvas redraws.  That's because changing obj.x and obj.y will result in 2 redraws.  It's more efficient to change both obj.x & obj.y and then do 1 redraw.

Comment: I have render() function, that takes array of objects as argument, clears the canvas and redraws all objects. Now, when I change some property of these objects (for example height,x,y,...), I want to get render() called to immediately show that change on canvas... So basically, I want to get a function called every time I change some property of one of these objects in array. Right now, I'm using setters and getters. If it would be just for the render, I could do it independently, but the problem is, I have some simple physics implemented, so I want to do collision check with other objects,...

Comment: I understand your situation better now.  I've changed my answer to get a little deeper into how physics engines process property changes.  Good luck with your project!